# Detect current bitrate of HTTP Live Streaming in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-video, http-live-streaming

When using Apple Live Streaming in Safari, is there any way to detect the current bitrate with  Javascript? Alternatively, can I detect which element of the .m3u8 is being played?

I've looked at the [HTMLMediaElement Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Reference/HTMLMediaElementClassReference/HTMLMediaElement/HTMLMediaElement.html), but found no clues there. The src property always references the .m3u8 file, so that doesn't help.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like the WHATWG is trying to address that very concern. See their document about HTML5 video metrics here: http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Video_Metrics

Using the Safari web developer tools, you can see that Webkit has implemented the following properties on the HTMLVideoElement:

- webkitAudioDecodedByteCount
- webkitDecodedFrameCount
- webkitDroppedFrameCount
- webkitVideoDecodedByteCount

There isn't much documentation out there about these, but 
I found some [sample code](http://opensource.apple.com/source/WebCore/WebCore-1298/manual-tests/video-statistics.html) that might be helpful.

I'd be very interested to hear if these properties worked for you. Please post your feedback if you gain any insight.

Comment: Thanks, that looks potentially useful, though in Safari 5.1.7 I don't see those properties. I'll check Safari 6.0.1 to see if it's supported there.

Comment: Are you sure? I noted them on an old Windows build of 5.0.5 and in Chrome.

Comment: There weren't visible in the Web Inspector in Safari 5.1.7 on OS X Lion, or accessible via JS. I did see them in Chrome though.

Comment: Not visible in Safari 6.0.1 on OS X Lion either :(

Comment: I see the same on my Mac (OS X Lion/Safari 5.1.6). It is strange to see it implemented in Safari for Windows and not on the Mac. Too bad.

Comment: It's not there in Safari (as of 12)